# jquery AJAX missing object in server response

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a basic ajax call to my controller like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'Final/EditCustomer/' + '@Model.CustomerId',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

This is working fine so far, controller action gets called, in my customer object im including the Tenant object and the CustomerType object:

```
public IActionResult EditCustomer(int ID)
{
    var customer = new TCustomer();
    customer = _context.TCustomer
        .Where(c => c.CustomerId == 1)
        .Include(x => x.Tenant)
        .Include(y => y.CustomerType)
        .FirstOrDefault();
    return new ObjectResult(customer);
}
```

Now Here it gets strange, when i retrieve the object in my ajax call, i can see in the console that the Customer object has values with a CustomerType object in it, **BUT** i dont get the Tenant Object from the Server, even though it tells me it got sent from the controller:

**EDIT**

TCustomer Model:

```
    namespace DAL.Entities
    {
    [Table("T_Customer")]
    public partial class TCustomer
    {
    public TCustomer()
    {
        TCustomerDocument = new HashSet<TCustomerDocument>();
        TLinkMgmtNetToCustomer = new HashSet<TLinkMgmtNetToCustomer>();
        TLinkPersonToCustomer = new HashSet<TLinkPersonToCustomer>();
        TLinkSrvAppAcntToCustomer = new HashSet<TLinkSrvAppAcntToCustomer>       ();
        TPersonalAccount = new HashSet<TPersonalAccount>();
        TUserFavoritCustomer = new HashSet<TUserFavoritCustomer>();
    }

    [Column("Customer_ID")]
    [Key]
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    //[Required]
    //[MaxLength(250)]
    //public string Customer { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(250)]
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    [Column("Old_SiteID")]
    public int? OldSiteId { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string ImportQueryName { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "datetime")]
    public DateTime? ImportDate { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string FirmIndex { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string BskNumberCustomer { get; set; }
    public bool MaintenanceReasonRequired { get; set; }
    [Column("Tenant_ID")]
    public int TenantId { get; set; }
    [Column("CustomerType_ID")]
    public int CustomerTypeId { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string UpdateUser { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "datetime")]
    public DateTime? UpdateDate { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string AddUser { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "datetime")]
    public DateTime? AddDate { get; set; }
    public bool? Recording { get; set; }
    [Column("CH_Location")]
    public bool? ChLocation { get; set; }
    public bool? ProactiveSurveillance { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Customer")]
    public virtual ICollection<TCustomerDocument> TCustomerDocument { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("Customer")]
    public virtual ICollection<TLinkMgmtNetToCustomer> TLinkMgmtNetToCustomer { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("Customer")]
    public virtual ICollection<TLinkPersonToCustomer> TLinkPersonToCustomer { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("Customer")]
    public virtual ICollection<TLinkSrvAppAcntToCustomer> TLinkSrvAppAcntToCustomer { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("Customer")]
    public virtual ICollection<TPersonalAccount> TPersonalAccount { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("Customer")]
    public virtual ICollection<TUserFavoritCustomer> TUserFavoritCustomer { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CustomerTypeId")]
    [InverseProperty("TCustomer")]
    public virtual TCustomerType CustomerType { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("TenantId")]
    [InverseProperty("TCustomer")]
    public virtual TTenant Tenant { get; set; }

}
```

}

Comment: It would be helpful if you could include the exact  responseText returned, and also what the exact definition of your `TCustomer` class is

Comment: You can not access razor object in jquery ..try get the value from generated HTML to get @model object

Comment: Given that the OP states he's getting a response, just not the one expected, it follows logically that the use of Razor in the JS is put in a valid place in his cshtml file.

Comment: @syed mhamudul hasan akash Razor code is valid like this and working as it should

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Link to the screenshot of the server response [link](http://1.1m.yt/-_Zm60y.png)

Comment: Shouldn't your InverseProperty attribute value be `Tenant` instead of `TCustomer` ?